# using local session to maintain state

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use local session storage to maintain state in my web app, especially if/when the user opens several tabs in his browser.

I have some data that is injected in the HTML on the server. In the document.ready section of the page, I have something like this:

```
MyStorage = window.sessionStorage;
MyStorage.setItem('MyVar', $('#TheVar').html());
```

If later on I write this:

```
ThisVar = MyStorage.getItem('MyVar');
ThisVar = 3;
```

Will the value in the session storage also become 3? And, will the value of all the variables ThisVar in other tabs also be 3 when I change the value of ThisVar in one tab?

Thanks.

Comment: No because you are changing, the local variable ThisVar, you would have write the value back into your sessionStorrage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, because you're assigning a new value to `ThisVar`, not to the `sessionStorage` key-value pair.
2. No, the variables are not magically updated. `getItem` returns the value, thus the string of the stored key.

Comment: Then is there a way to assign its reference instead?

Comment: @frenchie You have to use `sessionStorage.getItem('MyVar')` whenever you want the latest value.

Comment: ok, thanks, I got it. It would only work for objects because objects are reference types but sessionStorage only works with strings and these are only passed by value; is that correct?

Comment: @frenchie Yes, you are correct. Here's a link to the documentation, for future visitors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage

Comment: Rob, I was wondering if you could look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561138/javascript-warning-on-closure-compiler

Answer (score 0):

1. try to avoid Uppercase variables, this naming-convention is for Classes only.
2. use the keyword `var` to initialise you variables.
3. (answer to your question) No. You are not working on references, the `localStorage.getItem()`function returns the value as string, and not as a reference. You need to use the `localStorage.setItem()` function as you did in the first place, to update the Storage. Thats why, I'd recommend you work directly on the storage and not use extra variables. (On the other hand you could use a function, which updates the storage when you change the value of your variable.)